# Do all (or most) religions believe in the existence of an afterlife?

Tags: comparative, underworld, afterlife

I'm talking about both modern and ancient religions that we know of.

- Christianity -> Heaven, Hell
- Greco Roman -> Hades
- Egyptian -> Anubis, Osiris

among many others. Are there any exceptions to this statement?

Comment: Isn't the existence of an afterlife the main selling point for a religion?

Comment: Another way of couching Girsan's observation is that funerary rites are one of the things that distinguish the earliest humans from animals, and one of the principle concerns of religion is the inevitability of death, and how we respond to that knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Buddhism and Hinduism believe in many lives, and do have heavens and hells.

- [Naraka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naraka_(Hinduism)) (a Hindu hell)
- [Vaikuntha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaikuntha) (a Hindu heaven)

At a high level, a distinction between these two religions is that in Buddhism, everything is impermanent and therefore illusory (including heaven and hell), as opposed to the Hindu conception of everything as cyclic and eternal.

- [Tian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tian) (the Chinese heaven)
- [Diyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diyu) (the Chinese hell)

The Chinese tradition is equally rich, and a function of some degree of [syncretism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncretism) between Buddhism, Taoism, Confucianism, and traditional folk religions.

Answer (score 1):

well I don't really know more than those couple you listed above but I do know that in norse mythology the viking who died bravely in battle went to valhalla while the unhonorable dead (the people that died of old age and that kind of stuff) went to helheim. in another religion- i don't know which one it is though - there was limbo kind of like the fields of asphodel in hades but in a more temporary kind of way. another one was that the jehovahs witness didn't believe in heaven or hell so they chose to believe the in between also known as purgatory.

but like I said above I don't really know more than those couple you listed before.